# Multiselect categories in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

One of catalogs consists of 3 levels of which the fourth is a differentiation in brands. Consider the following example as level 2 and 3

- Hatchbacks

  - Volkswagen
  - Volvo
  - Seat
  - Audi

Basically we want to show all products when a customer is browsing the hatchbacks. We made the Hatchbacks category an achor thus giving the client filtering options. This means that the underlying (3rd level) categories can be filtered as well. However only one category can be selected at a time. It is not possible to extend this with the Manadev extension. Since these brands are loaded from an ERP system every night it is not possible to use a dropdown attribute for brands as this might change at each update.

It there a possibility to adjust this?

Comment: The problem here is that you are moving the ERP limitaciones into the ecommerce platform, brand  should be an attribute not a category brands doesn't change every night a volvo car will be a volvo always, you can map erp categories to attribute options in every integration if does not exists then you will be able to use manadev or any other extension to do that.

Comment: I completely agree with your comment on this matter. It's not a desirable solution but we'll have to work with what we've been given.